# Cannot start Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface

I have a problem of using Cassandra.
when i trying cassandra/bin cassandra -f 
following exception:

```
ERROR 16:47:29,698 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:397)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.rebuildCQL3Metadata(CFMetaData.java:1867)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.rebuild(CFMetaData.java:1839)
at     org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.addColumnDefinitionsFromSchema(CFMetaData.java:1759)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromSchema(CFMetaData.java:1664)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.KSMetaData.deserializeColumnFamilies(KSMetaData.java:305)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.KSMetaData.fromSchema(KSMetaData.java:286)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTables.loadFromKeyspace(DefsTables.java:130)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadSchemas(DatabaseDescriptor.java:511)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:235)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:397)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.rebuildCQL3Metadata(CFMetaData.java:1867)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.rebuild(CFMetaData.java:1839)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.addColumnDefinitionsFromSchema(CFMetaData.java:1759)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromSchema(CFMetaData.java:1664)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.KSMetaData.deserializeColumnFamilies(KSMetaData.java:305)
at org.apache.cassandra.config.KSMetaData.fromSchema(KSMetaData.java:286)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTables.loadFromKeyspace(DefsTables.java:130)
at  org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadSchemas(DatabaseDescriptor.java:511)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:235)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:442)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:485)
Exception encountered during startup: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

Cassandra 2.0
ubuntu 12.04

Thank you for your help in resolving this, in advance.

Comment: Did you have another version of Cassandra installed before?

Comment: thanks @charly no it my first cassandra installation.and i reinstall the cassandra and now it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6183) that can happen when replaying mutations of a dropped table.  It's fixed for the upcoming 2.0.2.